# Use maven meta-project to push war to tomcat

Tags: maven, tomcat, maven-tomcat-plugin

We use maven to build one of our webprojekts to a war file. With tomcat7-maven-plugin, developers can push the project to a tomcat server out of their build-directory.

We would now like to also use maven, to keep our production tomcat-servers up to date. I thought about a meta-project, with a dependency to the webproject, which would just download the war file from the maven repository and push it to the webserver.

I tried to give it a shoot but failed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
   <artifactId>www1</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>www1</name>
   <url>http://www.example.de</url>
   <distributionManagement>
      <repository>
         <id>internal</id>
         <url>http://archiva:8008/archiva/repository/internal/</url>
      </repository>
   </distributionManagement>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
               <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
               <server>TomcatAlpha</server>
               <path>/search</path>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
         <artifactId>webproject</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
         <type>war</type>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <repositories>
      <repository>
         <id>snapshots</id>
         <name>Archiva Managed Snapshot Repository</name>
         <url>http://archiva:8008/archiva/repository/snapshots/</url>
         <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
         </releases>
         <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
         </snapshots>
      </repository>
      <repository>
         <id>internal</id>
         <name>Archiva Managed Internal Repository</name>
         <url>http://archiva:8008/archiva/repository/internal/</url>
         <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
         </releases>
         <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
         </snapshots>
      </repository>
   </repositories>
</project>
```

Unfortunately this project does nothing

```
$ mvn  tomcat7:redeploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building www1 3.0.3-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:redeploy (default-cli) @ www1 >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) @ www1 ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/wb/tmp/maven/new/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) @ www1 ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ www1 ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/wb/tmp/maven/new/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ www1 ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ www1 ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/wb/tmp/maven/new/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.2:jar (default-jar) @ www1 ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] Building jar: /home/wb/tmp/maven/new/target/www1-3.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:redeploy (default-cli) @ www1 <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:redeploy (default-cli) @ www1 ---
[INFO] Skipping non-war project
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.213s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Oct 14 10:31:33 CEST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/304M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to accomplish this or am I trying to use maven the wrong way?